# Can't get Admob working in my Cordova Android app in VS2017

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2017, admob

I've been going round in circles here, trying to get the Admob Pro plugin to work. I get endless build errors. If anyone has recently got Admob ads working in their Cordova project (using any plugin) I'd be grateful for the exact steps I need to follow to do that. I don't mind which plugin. I say recently because I imagine a lot depends on the particular version numbers all working with each other. I've been using:

- VS Community 2017
- Cordova 6.3.1
- cordova-android 5.2.1
- Android target API level 28
- AdMob Plugin Pro 2.49.0
- PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION 18.2.0
- Google Mobile Ads SDK for Cordova 7.49.0

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

To target api 28 you'll need cordova-Android 8 or later and cordova as well. I was using vs community 2015 but decided to use this as an opportunity to migrate to using VsCode which I find a much less opaque since everything is done from the command line. I had to upgrade Cordova to 8.1.1. You also need to be aware of GDPR consent, and of the upcoming CCPA changes. I use the following plugins:

https://github.com/Longs/cordova-plugin-ad-admob.git NB I haven't uploaded the additional functionality to pass in GDPR consent yet and this is Android only in any case.

https://github.com/dragonbane0/cordova-plugin-google-consent.git NB this is incompatible with Cordova 9 so I use it with Cordova 8.1

"cordova-plugin-extras-google-play-services": "^1.0.5"

"cordova-plugin-ad-admob-sdk": "^1.0.1"

From memory I believe that one or more of the plugins generated an issue with the new AndroidX versions so I needed to add:

"cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.0",

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I'll try loading Cordova 8. I think it has to be installed separately to VS 2017, and VS 2019 doesn't seem to use it at all.